# Inverse of an infinite matrix with factorial entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, infinite-matrices

Has anyone come across the following matrix?
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{1!}&\frac{1}{2!}&\frac{1}{3!}&\cdots\\
-\frac{1}{2!}&-\frac{1}{3!}&-\frac{1}{4!}&\cdots\\
\frac{1}{3!}&\frac{1}{4!}&\frac{1}{5!}&\cdots\\
-\frac{1}{4!}&-\frac{1}{5!}&-\frac{1}{6!}&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I am particularly interested in finding $A^{-1}$.

Comment: If we get rid of the $-$'s, then youo have a Hankel matrix, for what that's worth

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If the minuses weren’t there, and it were an infinite Hankel matrix, what would its inverse be?

Comment: no idea ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I remember [a solved problem which at first glance looks similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619051/inverse-of-an-infinite-matrix-with-factorials) - but I didn't compare it to your question too thorougly so the techniques used there may or may not be useful for your problem.

Comment: Have you seen this older answer of mine which handles a very similar case: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863333/1714 using LDU-decomposition and inverting the triangular/diagonal components first.

Comment: It seems, that using LDU-decomposition and Euler-summation for the final dot-products gives the infinite zero-matrix as inverse.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, how can we find it's determinant?

Comment: Jason - did something happen with your question in the meantime? (since Aug 2018)

Answer (score 1):

The LDU-decomposition gives dot-products of rows & columns of the following matrices, whose  decomposition of entries is much obvious and simple even for the infinite case and allow Cesaro or Eulersummation, which seem to give always zero (I've checked this for a handful of leading dot-products). 
The row-scaled left and column-scaled right matrices of the product look like

$$
\small \begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|rrrrrrrrr|} 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &u^{-1} &\cdot _\mathfrak E&(d^{-1}&\cdot l^{-1})& = &\Large 0  &  &  & 5 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 7 & 14 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 9 & 30 & 27 & 9 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 11 & 55 & 77 & 44 & 11 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 13 & 91 & 182 & 156 & 65 & 13 & 1 & 0 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 15 & 140 & 378 & 450 & 275 & 90 & 15 & 1 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & .. &  \\ 
\hline\\ 
 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 1 & -3 & 6 & -10 & 15 & -21 & 28 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & -5 & 15 & -35 & 70 & -126 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -7 & 28 & -84 & 210 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -9 & 45 & -165 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -11 & 66 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -13 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & ... &  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \\ 
 .. & .. & .. & .. & .. & .. & .. & .. & ... &  & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & ... & .. & | \\ 
\hline
 \end{array}$$
where $u,d,l$ are the similarity-scaled versions of $U,D,L$. Because the results of the dotproducts - taken by Euler-summation - are all zero (supposedly), the required inverse similarity-scaling of the result-matrix is irrelevant and doesn't change its character of being a zero-matrix.

---

You can check some entries in the first column of the results using the `sumalt()`-procedure in `Pari/GP` which is a Cesaro-sum-related version of divergent summation of alternating series.

```
sumalt(k=1,(-1)^k*1*(2*k-1)) \\first row by first column

   vector(12,k,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+0,2))    \\second row check only
sumalt(k=2,(-1)^k*binomial(k+0,2)*(2*k-1)) \\second row by first column

   vector(12,k,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+1,4))    \\3'rd row check only
sumalt(k=3,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+1,4)*(2*k-1))\\3'rd row by first column

   vector(12,k,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+2,6))    \\4'th row check only
sumalt(k=4,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+2,6)*(2*k-1))\\4'rd row by first column


   vector(12,k,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+3,8))    \\5'th row check only
sumalt(k=5,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+3,8)*(2*k-1))\\5'rd row by first column

   vector(12,k,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+4,10))    \\6'th row check only
sumalt(k=6,-(-1)^k*binomial(k+4,10)*(2*k-1))\\6'rd row by first column
```